# ng-pattern for exclusion group of numbers

Tags: angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I have a list of exclusion numbers.

for example
(400276|400615|402914|404625)

the pattern should not let me enter into the input any of these numbers as the first 6 digits
example

**400276**123 .BAD. because the value init with a number to exclude

**400277**123 .OK

I try something like that

"^[^] (400|405)"

but is not working

how can I use a pattern for exclude this first 6 digits

Comment: Use a negative lookahead - `/^(?!400276|400615|402914|404625)/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew   it works thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern - `^[^] (400|405)` - matches the start of the string, then any char, a space, and either `400` or `405`.

What you need is a [**negative lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/^(?!400276|400615|402914|404625)/
  ^^^                           ^
```

It will fail the match of a string that starts with these values.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IlpcqJ/1/).